# yii textfield and dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii, textfield

```
<td><?php echo $form->textField($model,'SO_month'); ?><?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'SO_month',array('Months'=>'Months','Years'=>'Years'),array());?></td>
```

i don't get it . my form works like this i will input an integer for the SO months then i will choose between months and years if i choose months it just input the months but if i choose years it will be multiplied by 12 then input what was happening is instead of the integer i am getting the selected radio button . help me please..

Comment: What radio button? I see a textfield and a drop down list

Comment: im sorry it dropdown not radio typo error please help .. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same **attribute** for the *textField* and the *dropDownList*.
You will need to add an additional attribute to your model (maybe **date_type**)

```
class MyModel extends CActiveRecord {
     public $date_type;
     ...
```

And then do something like:

```
<td>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'SO_month'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'date_type',array('Months'=>'Months','Years'=>'Years'),array());?>
</td>
```

Then in your action where the form is submitted to, you can simply check which type was selected and handle as necessary:

```
if ($model->date_type == "Years"){
    $model->SO_month = $model->SO_month * 12;
}
```

Comment: if i changed my dropdownlist name into 'data_type' my form is getting stuck into continues loading .

Comment: Did you add "data_type" to your model?

Comment: is it possible i create a dropdown without connecting it to the model .

Comment: can you help me on my project cause im a newbie in yii

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to put it in to the model? How are you going to validate it then?

Comment: TmpEmployeeEducationController cannot find the requested view "create".      im getting an error like this ..

Comment: That has nothing to do with this, that is you calling $this->render("create"); from the TmpEmployeeEducationController  and the view doesn't exists

Comment: can you look at my whole form , model and controller ?

Comment: Ok, mail me me[at]brettgregson.com

Comment: thanks, im rushing because my deadline is in 2 days.. i already sent the files thank you .